# Получение значения из input формы при onSubmit событии

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form, submit

Имеется форма, на которую навешено событие `onSubmit`, могу я как-то получить значение поля `input` по совершению этого события?

При этом нельзя использовать id, навешенный на input, или ref-атрибут

```js
class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { valid: true }
    this.handlers = {
      onSubmit: (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const input = <здесь хотелось бы получить значение инпута>
        this.setState({ valid: EMAIL_VALIDATION_REG.test(input) || !input })
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Form { ...this.handlers }>
        <LabelText htmlFor="signupemail">Sign Up</LabelText>
        <FormInput
          valid={ this.state.valid }
          placeholder="Email Address" />
        { !this.state.valid && <FormValidLabel>Please enter a valid email address</FormValidLabel> }
        <SignUpButton>SIGN UP</SignUpButton>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: А по атрибуту name можно?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется что никак, потому что в React однонаправленный поток данных, то есть данные передаются от родителя к ребенку, а не наоборот. Лично я вижу здесь 2 варианта: не дробить форму на компоненты [как например в офф доках](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html), или сделать отдельное хранилище вне компонента для хранения данных `input.value` (аля `Redux store`)

Comment: предложил способ в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

`const input = event.target.value`

или

`const input = event.currentTarget.value`

Comment: Там форма будет, а не input. И вообще, это не единственная проблема кода из вопроса.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а если сделать также, только через Jqeury по форме найти тег input?

Comment: @Horchynskyi, и без jQuery можно `event.target.имяИнпута.value`, но это как-то не react'овский способ по дому лазить и собирать. Плюс, он this успешно потерял, так что `this.setState` всё равно грохнется.

Comment: @Qwertiy почему грохнется? собирается и отрабатывает ок

Comment: @Tvolex спасибо за способ, но, как уже отметили, лазить по dom не ок

Comment: @while1pass, потому что this is undefined для приведённого кода.

Answer (score 0):

Считывать значение инпута можно по событию `onChange`:

```html
 this.handlers = {
  ...
  onChange: (e) => {
    const currentInputValue = e.target.value
    ...
  }
```

Его класть в стейт компонента и с ним уже работатать по событию `onSubmit`

Также можно для инпута навесить атрибут `name` (что правильно согласно WCAG)

```
<FormInput name="email" type="email" valid={ isValid } placeholder="Email Address" />
```

и обращаться в `onSubmit`, как

```
e.target.elements.email.value
```